# Error in configuring jhipster project : I am having existing jhipster project which includes maven, hibernate, spring-boot

Tags: hibernate, maven, jhipster

When I am running command "mvn clean install" build failed. Error caused by :
Results :

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException:
>   Unable to start embedded Tomcat
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List)
>   throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
>   com.orderone.app.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.orderone.app.repository.UserRepository
>   com.orderone.app.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner
>   bean '(inner bean)#4711c601' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4711c601': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: order    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List)
>   throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
>   com.orderone.app.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.orderone.app.repository.UserRepository
>   com.orderone.app.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner
>   bean '(inner bean)#4711c601' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4711c601': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: order

Comment: If you check logs you will find nested error is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: order

Comment: Tell me what steps I need to follow to solve this error

Comment: nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: order

Comment: Other entities are working correctly but only this entity is throwing error....

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you create your entity *order* you should have look at your liquibase config which can be found under

```
src/main/resources/config/liquibase
```

In this folder you have a *master.xml* file which tells liquibase which changelogs to be used in order to create the db. The changelogs are placed under

```
src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog
```

Here you need to have a changelog which is generating your table oreder. For more details have a look at the  [here](http://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-entity/) or the video doc [here](http://jhipster.github.io/video-tutorial/). Cheers